# Possible to force leading or trailing spaces in scenario outline values?

Tags: karate

I have tried a number of ways to force a scenario outline to have leading or trailing spaces, but nothing has seemed to work.  Is this even possible within an outline?  I would prefer not to have to code test for every parameter and such multiple times, just to hard code these negative test scenarios.

Sample code for attempts:

```
Feature:
  Background:
            * configure continueOnStepFailure = true

  Scenario Outline: Scenario outline value is |<scenarioValue>|
        * print "scenario outline value - |<scenarioValue>|"

    Examples:
            | scenarioValue   | 
                | original        | 
                | "double-quoted" | 
                | 'single-quoted' | 
                |  leading space  | 
                | trailing space  |
                | " quote leading space" |
                | 'quote trailing space' |
                | (parentheses)   |
                | ( leading space parentheses) |
                    | \ leading backslash |
                    | / leading slash |
                    | < gtr/lt signs> |
                    | &nbsp; space code |
                    | &#160; space code 2 |
                    | &ensp; two space code |
                    | &emsp; four space code |
                    | \xa0 js space code |
```

Comment: I could see the same use in the replace text table - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#replace, such as replacing _ with a space

Answer (score 0):

Use the enhanced column markers as explained here and use quoted strings: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

For example:

```
Scenario Outline:
* match value == ' foo'
Examples:
    | value! |
    | ' foo' |
```